# I've installed meteor - where is npm?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I've [installed meteor](https://www.meteor.com/install) on my machine:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

My understanding is that it meteor runs off of [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and automatically installs it.  And node automatically installs [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

I'm working through the [Discover Meteor tutorial](https://book.discovermeteor.com/chapter/deploying#initializing-meteor-up) and it has me run:

```
npm install -g mup
```

But I get the following output:

```
-bash: npm: command not found
```

Do I need to run it from a different directory? Or download / install something extra onto my machine.  Add it to my PATH?

Comment: It's likely a $PATH problem. Could you check your $PATH variable? Then check to see if you have npm installed in your bin properly. If you do, add it to your $PATH and that should address your issue. If you don't, just reinstall Node.js directly, and that would likely resolve that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Meteor, it **does not** automatically install node && npm. When installing Meteor, it will download something called `dev_bundle` which has NodeJS and all the NPM modules needed by Meteor. All these modules are pre-compiled for your platform but are not "installed" per-se.

Check out this post if you want to use the node distribubtion included with Meteor: https://meteorhacks.com/how-meteor-uses-node. I suggest you just install Node on your own, though.

Comment: Yep, installed [node from the download page](https://nodejs.org/download/) and it fixed this issue.  Thanks!